# pandas query isnt recognizing f string or .format

Tags: python, pandas, format, string-formatting

All Im trying to do is pass a variable to a pandas .query function. I keep getting empty rows returned when I use a python string variable (even when its formatted).

This works

```
a = '1736_4_A1'
df = metaData.query("array_id == @a")
print(df)
```

**output:**

```
    array_id  wafer_id  slide position  array_no sample_id
0  1736_4_A1      1736      4       A1         1   Rat 2nd
```

But this does not work! I dont understand why

```
array = str(waferid) + '_' + str(slideid) + '_' + str(position)
a = f'{array}'

a = "{}_{}_{}".format(waferid, slideid, position) 
    
print(a)
df = metaData.query("array_id == @a")
print(df)
```

**output:**

```
1736_4_a1
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [array_id, wafer_id, slide, position, array_no, sample_id]
Index: []
```

I've spent too many hours on this. I feel like this should be simple! What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Position ("A1") is uppercase in your working example and lowercase in the other, try converting it to uppercase. `position.upper()`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.